Sorting Multiple Tables by IDs With a Single Function
I am looking to include tableCompletion-Progress in the sortTable() function alongside timeSpentTable. If I swap out timeSpentTable for   tableCompletion-Progress, it works. However, my goal is to include both tables in the sortTable function.
Is there a way to use document.querySelectorAll like:
table = document.querySelectorAll("timeSpentTable, tableCompletion-Progress");

Here is my code:


function openSheet(evt, sheetName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Time-Spent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Completion-Progress");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Lesson-Percentage-Correct");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Quiz-Percentage-Correct");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Dashboard-Key");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(sheetName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("timeSpentTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
.sort-btn {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4caf50;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color .5 ease-in;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #357834;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 1%;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #333;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Time-Spent")'>Participant Performance</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Completion-Progress")'>Lesson Progress</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Lesson-Percentage-Correct")' id="defaultOpen">Lesson Percentage
            Correct
        </button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Quiz-Percentage-Correct")'>Quiz Percentage Correct</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Dashboard-Key")'>Dashboard Key</button>
  </div>
  <div id="Dashboard-Key" class="Dashboard-Key" style="display:none">
    <table class="Dashboard-Key">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Lesson Number</th>
          <th>Lesson Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>L6</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L21</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L23</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L24</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L28</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L29</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Completion Status Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Completion Status</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td>Participants have completed parts 1-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Started</td>
        <td>Participants have started at least one part of the lesson</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Session Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Session</td>
        <td>Amount performed from start to finish in one sitting</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Quiz Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Quiz Number</th>
        <th>Quiz Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 1</td>
        <td>Cool-Down</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 2</td>
        <td>Challenge</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Time-Spent" class="Time-Spent" style="display:none">
    <table id="timeSpentTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Lesson<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Session<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Elapsed Time (Min)<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>First Start Date<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Last Start Date<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>17:32</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:05 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 06:48 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>09:35</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:18 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>14:20</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:42 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:56 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>11:05</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:32 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:43 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>19:10</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 09:50 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 10:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>08:25</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 10:58 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 11:06 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>13:50</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:45 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:59 PM</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Completion-Progress" class="Completion-Progress" style="display:none">
    <table id="tableCompletion-Progress">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L6
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L21
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L23
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"desc"")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L24
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L28
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L29
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(6,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(6,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Lesson-Percentage-Correct" class="Lesson-Percentage-Correct">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson</th>
          <th>Part</th>
          <th>Time Spent (Min)</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Quiz-Percentage-Correct" class="Quiz-Percentage-Correct">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson Identifier</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>




You really need to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Why not just give the tables you want to sort the same class, instead of trying to keep a list of ids around? I.e., give the tables a "sortable" class, then use getElementsByClassName, or even better, querySelectorAll('.sortable') and loop over the results?

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to get multiple ID's with document.querySelector()?

Yes you can use
var tables = document.querySelectorAll("#timeSpentTable, #tableCompletion-Progress");

then loop through table with:
tables.forEach(function (table) {...

Your sortTable should be like this:
function sortTable(n) {
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll("#timeSpentTable, #tableCompletion-Progress");
  tables.forEach(function (table) {
    var rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.rows;
      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        if (dir == "asc") {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount++;
      } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
          dir = "desc";
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

Here is the working code:


function openSheet(evt, sheetName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Time-Spent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Completion-Progress");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Lesson-Percentage-Correct");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Quiz-Percentage-Correct");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("Dashboard-Key");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(sheetName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


function sortTable(n) {
  var tables = document.querySelectorAll("#timeSpentTable, #tableCompletion-Progress");
  tables.forEach(function (table) {
    var rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
    switching = true;
    dir = "asc";
    while (switching) {
      switching = false;
      rows = table.rows;
      for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
        shouldSwitch = false;
        x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
        if (dir == "asc") {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) {
        rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
        switching = true;
        switchcount++;
      } else {
        if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
          dir = "desc";
          switching = true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}


document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
.sort-btn {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4caf50;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color .5 ease-in;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #357834;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 1%;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #333;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Time-Spent")'>Participant Performance</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Completion-Progress")'>Lesson Progress</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Lesson-Percentage-Correct")' id="defaultOpen">Lesson Percentage
            Correct
        </button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Quiz-Percentage-Correct")'>Quiz Percentage Correct</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick='openSheet(event,"Dashboard-Key")'>Dashboard Key</button>
  </div>
  <div id="Dashboard-Key" class="Dashboard-Key" style="display:none">
    <table class="Dashboard-Key">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Lesson Number</th>
          <th>Lesson Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>L6</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L21</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L23</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L24</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L28</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L29</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Completion Status Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Completion Status</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td>Participants have completed parts 1-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Started</td>
        <td>Participants have started at least one part of the lesson</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Session Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Session</td>
        <td>Amount performed from start to finish in one sitting</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Quiz Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Quiz Number</th>
        <th>Quiz Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 1</td>
        <td>Cool-Down</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 2</td>
        <td>Challenge</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Time-Spent" class="Time-Spent" style="display:none">
    <table id="timeSpentTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Lesson<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Session<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Elapsed Time (Min)<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>First Start Date<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Last Start Date<button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"asc")'>▲</button><button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>17:32</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:05 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 06:48 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>09:35</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:18 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>14:20</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:42 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:56 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>11:05</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:32 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:43 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>19:10</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 09:50 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 10:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>08:25</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 10:58 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 11:06 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>13:50</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:45 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:59 PM</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Completion-Progress" class="Completion-Progress" style="display:none">
    <table id="tableCompletion-Progress">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(0,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L6
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(1,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L21
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(2,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L23
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(3,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L24
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(4,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L28
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(5,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L29
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(6,"asc")'>▲</button>
            <button class="sort-btn" onclick='sortTable(6,"desc")'>▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Lesson-Percentage-Correct" class="Lesson-Percentage-Correct">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson</th>
          <th>Part</th>
          <th>Time Spent (Min)</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Quiz-Percentage-Correct" class="Quiz-Percentage-Correct">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson Identifier</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>




To answer the question you can use multiple selectors but # prefix is for an id.
var sortableTables = document.body.querySelectorAll("#timeSpentTable, #tableCompletion-Progress");
Now you don't really need that if you use a class like sortable-table or some such.
Note I attach the button listener to the tab-container to simplify and only have ONE listener not one for each button; then I can use the event to see which one was clicked AND use that to get the container it is attached to. ("event delegation" - search for that)
Here I also reduced the actual need for the id's by using classes and some data attributes on the buttons for the targets.  I used the id selector for the target but it might be a class with an index also using an nth-child CSS selector also ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
I removed all the event click from the HTML and used a listener to simplify things.
See how I toggle the hidden class I put in the CSS to avoid the more complex none and block values.
This is still quite verbose and can be reduced but I did this for clarity in learning.


var sortableTables = document.body.querySelectorAll("#timeSpentTable, #tableCompletion-Progress");
[...sortableTables].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', sortTable);
});
var toggleViews = document.querySelector(".tab-container");
toggleViews.addEventListener('click', openSheet);

function openSheet(event) {
  let me = event.target;
  let parentContainer = me.closest('.container');
  let tabContainer = event.currentTarget; // me.closest(".tab-container"); also works to get the tab container since that is where we attached our event handler.
  let tables = parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.table-container');
  [...tabContainer.querySelectorAll('.tablinks')].forEach((tab) => {
    tab
      .classList.toggle("active", false);
  });
  me.classList.toggle("active", true);
  let targetTable = document.querySelector(me.dataset.target);
  targetTable.classList.toggle('hidden', false);
  let siblings = [...tables]
    .filter(c => c.nodeType == 1 && c != targetTable);
  [...siblings].forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.toggle('hidden', true);
  });
}

function sortTable(event) {
  let table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  const index = [...event.target.parentElement.closest('tr').children].indexOf(event.target.parentElement);
  table = event.target.parentElement.closest('table'); //document.getElementById("timeSpentTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[index];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[index];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
.sort-btn {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-bottom: 4px solid #4caf50;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color .5 ease-in;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #357834;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 1%;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #333;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-container">
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Time-Spent">Participant Performance</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Completion-Progress">Lesson Progress</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Lesson-Percentage-Correct" id="defaultOpen">Lesson Percentage Correct</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Quiz-Percentage-Correct">Quiz Percentage Correct</button>
    <button class="tablinks" data-target="#Dashboard-Key">Dashboard Key</button>
  </div>
  <div id="Dashboard-Key" class="table-container Dashboard-Key hidden">
    <table class="Dashboard-Key">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Lesson Number</th>
          <th>Lesson Title</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>L6</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L21</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L23</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L24</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L28</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>L29</td>
        <td>Example</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Completion Status Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Completion Status</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Completed</td>
        <td>Participants have completed parts 1-3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Started</td>
        <td>Participants have started at least one part of the lesson</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Session Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th>Meaning</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Session</td>
        <td>Amount performed from start to finish in one sitting</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Quiz Key</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Quiz Number</th>
        <th>Quiz Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 1</td>
        <td>Cool-Down</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quiz 2</td>
        <td>Challenge</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Time-Spent" class="table-container Time-Spent hidden">
    <table id="timeSpentTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Lesson<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Session<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Elapsed Time (Min)<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>First Start Date<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>Last Start Date<button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>17:32</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:05 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 06:48 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>09:35</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:18 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>14:20</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:42 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-18 07:56 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>11:05</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:32 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-19 08:43 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>19:10</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 09:50 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-20 10:09 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>08:25</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 10:58 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-21 11:06 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>13:50</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:45 PM</td>
          <td>2024-03-22 11:59 PM</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Completion-Progress" class="table-container Completion-Progress hidden">
    <table id="tableCompletion-Progress">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L6
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L21
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L23
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L24
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L28
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
          <th>L29
            <button class="sort-btn sort-asc">▲</button><button class="sort-btn sort-desc">▼</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>Completed</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Lesson-Percentage-Correct" class="table-container Lesson-Percentage-Correct hidden">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson</th>
          <th>Part</th>
          <th>Time Spent (Min)</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3"><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td rowspan="3">L6</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>7.9</td>
          <td>20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>15.7</td>
          <td>25%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>17.3</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:large"><b>Total Time Spent:</b></td>
          <td><b>41.9</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="Quiz-Percentage-Correct" class="table-container Quiz-Percentage-Correct hidden">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Participant</th>
          <th>Lesson Identifier</th>
          <th>Percentage Correct</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:bdcUMtest@bdc.org">bdcUMtest@bdc.org</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example6@example.com">example6@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 2</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example7@example.com">example7@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example8@example.com">example8@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example9@example.com">example9@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="mailto:example10@example.com">example10@example.com</a></td>
          <td>L6 Quiz 1</td>
          <td>10%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>




I could/should probably have used const not let for most of the declarations.
